# Can't figure out the hierarchy of AndroidX and Jetpack

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have been studying Android for two years, and now I am completely confused about the hierarchy of AndroidX libraries.

To be more concrete: We have AndroidX, Jetpack and Jetpack Compose libraries.

How are they related?
In Jetpack Compose, I've seen packages from AndroidX and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

`androidx` is a namespace that include the Android Jetpack libraries, and Compose is just one of them.

The first line of [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) docs :

> The androidx namespace comprises the [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) libraries.

And when you use a compose dependency you can see the namespace, e.g.  `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation`.